# UI Slider value show "Or more" and "Or less"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I wounder if there is any possiblity to change to maximum and minimum value to a range-slider to search values between (example) "40 or less" and "60 or more". So if the standard maximum value is 60 and the minimum is 40, the slider will work just as usually between 41 and 59, but when set the right handlebar to 60 the label will show "60 or more" and left handlebar to 40 the label will show "40 or less".

**Example:** Values min:40 max:60. When set the left handlebar to middle of the slider (50) and the right handlebar to maximum it will search for results between 50 and unlimited higher value, and the label will show "50 - 60 or more".

```
function{
    $( "#range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 40,
        max: 60,
        step: 1,
        values: [ 40, 60 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#label" ).val( "Value: " + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] + "");
        }
    });
    $( "#label" ).val( "Value: " + $( "#range" ).slider( "values", 0 )+ " - " + $( "#range"     ).slider( "values", 1 ) + "");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom event, dude!
What's the problem of defining

```
$("#range").bind('rightIsMax',function(e,leftVal,rightMaxVal){
   $( "#label" ).val( "Value: "+leftVal+" - " + rightMaxVal + " or more");
});
```

When `ui.values[ 1 ]===60` then `$("#range").trigger('rightIsMax',ui.values[0],ui.values[1]);`

Comment: Ofcource you can refer for a getter of the max value  for the slider instead of `===60` comparison. Which jquery-ui slider should have but I'm not familiar with that spesific widget

Comment: Sorry I am not so good at coding but I have manage to get the UI slider to work. Could you maybe include your code in my code-example in my first post? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, actually I've made a more deep research and I've found that I can't find which one of the two sliders was moved. Do you have some progress about that issue?

Comment: Hmm not sure how you mean now, do you mean you cant get my code example to run? One sliders dont move?

Comment: Oh my bad, ok I'll post an example in a few minutes

Comment: Would really appreciate an code-example, have tried get this code correct for a while now without any success.

Comment: Well if you talk about the custom event , actually there's no need it duplicates the `change` event. But I'll show you an example just to see how it's done

Comment: Well for some reason the create event isn't triggered so I can't bind my custom event http://jsfiddle.net/wJsbU/1/ but anyway no need it totally duplicates the slider events so it's useless. But here's a better example http://jsfiddle.net/wJsbU/

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a handler for the change event to paint your label:

http://jsfiddle.net/2MBGh/

```
change: function (event, ui) {
    var label = $('#label');

    switch (ui.value) {
        // min
        case 0:
            label.text('Less than 0.');
            break;
        // max
        case 10:
            label.text('Greater than 10.');
            break;
        default:
            label.text(ui.value);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is near the result I am looking for, but I wounder how I do now if I want two handlebars, one for minimun and one for maximum (and then also two labels so the result can write out for exampe "Value: 40-60 or more"). Like this one: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range. Can you please explain if you got a minut? Thanks.

Comment: A bit strange the label dont show up untill movement of the slider.

Comment: @Wobot because the code that sets the label val initially is missing

Answer (score 0):

Havent really solve this question yet so I made a standard jsfiddle with the slider if anybody wants to try modify the labels.

http://jsfiddle.net/77SsQ/4/

Thanks.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 40,
        max: 60,
        values: [ 40, 60 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "" + $( "#range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - " + $( "#range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
​
```